# Troubles when grouping a column data in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, extract

all.

I´m trying to extract a vector from a column that contains all the values that belong to a specific type.

To be more concise, I have a table with 5000 rows. The column "Types" can take the values A,B,C or D. I need to extract all the rows that belong to a specific type, like A.

I want to use the function group_by from the library dplyr and I´m trying:

```
dplyr::group_by(my_database,type)
```

or even

```
dplyr::group_by(my_database,type,A)
```

but I don´t get what I need. Does anyone know how to proceed?

NOTE: I can´t use the function %>% because for some strange reason R says "could not find %>% function".

I appreciate a lot your kind responses in advance.

Comment: Can you specify the difference between what you get and what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Patrick. Of course I can. I get the whole table again and I just want to have a collection of rows that meet a certain criteria. In this case, that the type in column "types" is A. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R can't find `%>%` because you have not loaded a library which uses it. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
```

The function that you're looking for is `filter`.

```
my_database %>% filter(Types == "A")
```

Spend some time with the `dplyr` documentation ([introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)) or a good tutorial.

Comment: `dplyr` imports `%>%` from `magrittr` so make sure `magrittr` is installed. Also "downloaded" is not the same as "installed" or "loaded into R".

Comment: Great response. You were right in all aspects. Thanks a lot, neilfws.

Comment: Anyway, is it not possible to get to the same point by using group_by? Just curious....

Comment: No. `group_by` is for grouping variables prior to some kind of summary. For example, if you wanted to calculate mean of the values for type A, B, C...

Comment: Ok, I understand. So let´s take that I wanted to calculare for instance the mean for type A. Then should I have written this?:    my_database  %>%   group_by(Type)   %>%   summarise(…) or would I miss anything? Thank you